# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'logPolar' opencv3.0

Tags: opencv3.0

I am trying to run `opencv3.0` demos (`./opencv/sources/samples/python2`) and some of the functions are returning:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute" one os them was 'LINE_AA' for facedetect.py and houghlines.py.

In these cases I have just removed `LINE_AA` from the call, and it worked fine.

Before:

```
cv2.putText(dst, s, (x+1, y+1), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.0, (0, 0, 0), thickness = 2, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)

cv2.putText(dst, s, (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
```

After:

```
cv2.putText(dst, s, (x+1, y+1), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.0, (0, 0, 0), thickness = 2)

cv2.putText(dst, s, (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.0, (255, 255, 255))
```

Although, for `logpolar.py` I am also getting:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "logpolar.py", line 16, in <module>
img2 = cv2.logPolar(img, (img.shape[0]/2, img.shape[1]/2), 40, cv2.WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'logPolar'
```

In this case I am not sure what I should do.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you're obviously **not** running opencv3.0, but some 2.4 version (which does not have cv2.logPolar)

Comment: After many problems I have given up on python and built opencv 3.0 in my machine. I am now using C/C++